# why the xlsxwriter conditional formatting does not work

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

my two conditional formatting statements are completely the same, however, the first works while the second doesn't.

i wonder why it happens and how to fix it?

```
wb= writer.book
ws= writer.sheets['Sheet1']
ws.conditional_format('B2:L86', {'type':      '3_color_scale',
                                 'min_value': 0,
                                 'mid_value':50,
                                 'max_value': 100,
                                 'min_color': 'CC0000',
                                 'mid_color': 'white',
                                 'max_color': '006600'}
                                    )

ws.conditional_format('M2:M86', {'type':      '3_color_scale',
                                 'min_value': 0,

                                 'max_value': 1100,
                                 'min_color': 'CC0000',
                                 'mid_color': 'white',
                                 'max_color': '006600'})
ws.set_column(0, 13, 10)
wb.close()
writer.save()
```

picture is:
[image]

Comment: They are *not* "completely the same".

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue, related or otherwise with the way the colors are specified. They should be in HTML format like `'#CC0000'` and `'#006600'`.

> my two conditional formatting statements are completely the same

They aren't. The second one doesn't have a mid range value and the max value is higher. Fixing that and the color issue should give you the output you expect:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_conditional.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

ws = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
ws.conditional_format('B2:L86', {'type':      '3_color_scale',
                                 'min_value': 0,
                                 'mid_value': 50,
                                 'max_value': 100,
                                 'min_color': '#CC0000',
                                 'mid_color': 'white',
                                 'max_color': '#006600'})

ws.conditional_format('M2:M86', {'type':      '3_color_scale',
                                 'min_value': 0,
                                 'mid_value': 550,
                                 'max_value': 1100,
                                 'min_color': '#CC0000',
                                 'mid_color': 'white',
                                 'max_color': '#006600'})
ws.set_column(0, 13, 10)
writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]